# Как отобразить на каждой фото всей галереи ALT текст из заданного списка? Или почему не отображаются jpg с именем в кириллице?

Tags: python, django

Всем привет. Я очень начинающий, первый проект. Прошу помочь.
Вывожу в django шаблоне все фотографии из каталога и применяю к ним ALT текст из имени файла.

```
<a href="{{ MEDIA_URL }}images/thumbs/{{ image }}">
    <img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}images/{{ image }}" alt="{{ image }}">
</a>
```

Проблема была бы решена, но фото с кириллицей не отображается в шаблоне. Можно ли это решить?
Если нет, то может быть можно применить список или кортеж, в котором заранее прописаны 100 ALT текстов, к примеру, и чтобы по списку применялся ALT текст к каждой фото (похоже на костыли, но я не знаю как решить проблему).
[image: не отображается картинка с кириллицей в имени]
Спасибо.

Comment: django 4, python 3.9

Comment: просто используйте транслит, ри сохранении изображений. Например библиотека `pytils`

Comment: Вадим, огромное спасибо! Ответ заслуживает жирного лайка!

Comment: пожалуйста) можете сами оформить ввиде ответа, вставив использование внутри своих моделей в ответ. чтобы другие могли найти быстро пример

Comment: Жаль, но так не выйдет. Тематика "Эвакуатор", в каждом АЛТе будет это слово, а буква "Э" коряво обратно транслитирируется. На выходе "Евакуатор..". Буду думать как из заготовленного списка добавлять альты. Если кто подскажет, буду благодарен. Спасибо.

Comment: выложите часть кода своей модели

Comment: Мне кажется некорректно тут дублировать, открыл новый вопрос, т.к. задачу уже другая. Я уже почти решил её путём использования списка, но в конце упёрся в новую проблему. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1465949/Итерация-по-списку-в-шаблоне-django