# Итерация по списку в шаблоне django

Tags: python, django

Есть фотогалерея, которая выводится из каталога **циклом** следующим образом (весь цикл не привожу, он массивный и суть не в нём):

```
<a href="{{ MEDIA_URL }}images/thumbs/{{ image }}">
<img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}images/{{ image }}" alt="{{ alt_text.0 }}">
```

Во views.py

```
def photo(request):
path = settings.MEDIA_ROOT
img_list = os.listdir(path + '/images/thumbs')
i = 0
alt_text = ('первое фото', 'второе фото', 'третье фото')
context = {'images': img_list,
           'alt_text': alt_text,
            'i': i}

return render(request, "photo/photo.html", context)
```

То есть я создал список alt_text для применении ALT к каждой фотографии.
Если в шаблоне я указываю `alt="{{ alt_text.0 }}` - то ALT текст присваивается к фотографии, но у меня их много, поэтому пытался через переменную 'i', и в конце цикла ставил i += 1, но такой фокус не работает. То есть код `alt="{{ alt_text.i }}` не работает.

Помогите пожалуйста с идеей, тапками прошу не кидать, все с чего-то начинали. Цель - применить следующий элемент списка к ALT тексту следующего изображения, пока изображения есть.
Спасибо.

Comment: а `alt_text[i]` - не работает ?

Comment: Да, так тоже не работает. Could not parse the remainder: '[i]' from 'alt_text.[i]'

Comment: точку-то уберите :). но может и не работает, я им не пользуюсь

Comment: Да, с точкой ошибся. Но и без нее тоже самое Could not parse the remainder: '[i]' from 'alt_text[i]'

Comment: зачем вообще такие костыли. Просто добавьте поле в модели к каждой фото с alt. Пишите там любое значение или через ChoiceField сделайте выбор из списка

Answer (score 0):

просто добавьте поле alt в модель.

```
class Image(models.Model):
    .......
    ALT_CHOICES = (
        ('1', 'alt1'),
        ('2', 'alt2'),
    )
    alt = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

или через выбор из допустимых значений

```
class Image(models.Model):
    .......
    ALT_CHOICES = (
        ('1', 'alt1'),
        ('2', 'alt2'),
    )
    alt = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
```

Comment: Спасибо, ну теперь придётся и модель создавать)) Т.к. в части фотогалереи у меня ее нет. У меня все изображения загружены были просто по ftp. А выводились они банальным перебором всех jpg файлов в div.